# Intersection of Two Planes with one plane having only one parameter

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 2 equations.
 $$5x - 7y + 2z = 0$$ $$y = 0$$

I've read you can get the vector a line by getting the cross product of the normals of 2 planes. For the second equation would the normal vector be the zero vector?

I've also read that if a normal of the plane is just a scalar of the second plane then the two are parallel, given the two equations above, how can I tell if they are parallel without the $x$ and $z$ components?

Comment: The normal vector for the second plane is $(0,1,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normal vector of first plane is $(5,-7,2)$ and $(0,1,0)$ is normal vector of second , they are not parallel. the normal vector of a plane $ax+by+cz=d$ is $(a,b,c)$, everything else you said is correct